# Htaccess 301 redirect for domain only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a list of 301 Redirects like this inside htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage1.php http://www.domain.com/newpage1.php
Redirect 301 /oldpage2.php http://www.domain.com/newpage2.php
Redirect 301 /oldpage3.php http://www.domain.com/newpage3.php
...
```

Now these pages shall be redirected only for a certain domain (there are other domains now pointing to the same location like www.domain.com).

E.g. **www.domain.com/oldpage1.php** shall be redirected, but **www.sub.domain.com/oldpage1.php** not.

So whats the way to apply these redirects only for www.domain.com?

Thanks.

Comment: Use mod_rewrite's `RewriteRule` in combination with `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^oldpage1\.php/?$ newpage1.php [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^oldpage2\.php/?$ newpage2.php [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^oldpage3\.php/?$ newpage3.php [L,R=301]
```

**PS:** If you have several rules like above then it is much better to use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html).